# Build for JavaFX project not creating exe

Tags: java, deployment, javafx, packaging

I am trying to build a exe file for my JavaFx project. The project is wrote in Java 6 and i have downloaded the standalone JavaFX for Java 6.
When i try to build the build.xml file using ant it is successful but does not create the exe I think it could be because of this message before it completes the build.

> Skip [Exe Bundler (based on Inno Setup)] due to [Java Runtime does not
>   include lib\jfxrt.jar]

How do I go about fixing this?

**EDIT:**
Fixed  [How to change JAVA.HOME for Eclipse/ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288343/how-to-change-java-home-for-eclipse-ant)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution might be to use the build.xml to output a jar file. Then create a text file then rename it to .bat file that executes the jar. It is pretty straight forward, and if you want to be fancy make an installer that creates shortcuts to the bat file. The contents of the bat file should be as follows (the sample will remove the console from showing up, but if you want the console use java instead of javaw):

```
@echo off

rem ***** Memory Initialization args *****
SET MYPROPS=%MYPROPS% -Xms512m
SET MYPROPS=%MYPROPS% -Xmx1024m

@echo on
START javaw %MYPROPS% -jar <project_jar>.jar com.example.Main
@echo off
```