# setting JAVA_HOME in windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I am getting the following error when I try to run an ant buildfile in eclipse:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\mypath\myapp\BuildWar.xml:16: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7"
```

I located the jdk at C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe

I used the methods in [this blog entry](http://www.robertsindall.co.uk/blog/setting-java-home-variable-in-windows/) to create a system environmental variable in windows 7 called JAVA_HOME and mapped to C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\javac.exe .  When the error persisted, I restarted the computer, tried again, and got the same error.  I then changed the mapping of JAVA_HOME to C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\ and still got the same error.

Can anyone show me how to get past this error, so that I can run my ant build file in eclipse?

---

### EDIT:

I am getting the same exact error message again today when I try to run the ant buildfile, even though JAVA_HOME is set as per the answers below, and even though the path variable now includes %JAVA_HOME%\bin . I have checked the values of these environmental variables in the windows control  panel section for setting environmental variables, even though the eclipse console gives the above error message saying JAVA_HOME is set to a jre.  Does anyone have any suggestions about how to fix this recurring problem?

---

### SECOND EDIT:

Changing the Java Home in eclipse fixed this problem.  The eclipse Java Home is separate from the windows Java Home.

Comment: Map JAVA_HOME to C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17 only. Hope that fixes your problem.

Comment: @YogendraSingh +1 for helping.  My program runs now.  Thanks.

Comment: @YogendraSingh I am getting the same exact error message again today when I try to run the ant buildfile, even though JAVA_HOME is set as you instructed, and even though the path variable now includes %JAVA_HOME%\bin .  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please try running "java -version" from your command prompt and check if it is printing the right version?

Comment: @YogendraSingh Thank you.  The result of running java -version is java version "1.7.0_25" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b16) Java Hotspot(TM) 64-bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode).  Any more suggestions?

Comment: As next steps, I would suggest to add some "echo" statements to print "Path" and "Java_Home" value just before the failure statement. I am just thinking, if there is any override with in the build file.

Comment: @YogendraSingh Can you suggest a way to do something within the ant buildfile itself?  I would prefer not to add the complexity of writing a command line program.  My command line skills are beginner level, and so are my ant skills.  I am most comfortable writing code inside eclipse, and ant is a new part of eclipse for  me.

Comment: You may want to use "echo (http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html)" to print the values. Also you may want to run the build with -v option to receive the detailed error message.

Comment: @YogendraSingh Thank you.  It works now.  I put an explanation of the fix in the second edit to my original post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set JAVA_HOME to `C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\`

Then in your path variable add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`

Comment: +1 for trying to help.  And credit for the answer, because this is the actual syntax that I used.  My program runs now.  Thanks.

Comment: I made an edit to my original posting above describing how the error is back again, even though windows tells me that the environmental variables are still set properly.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What happens if you open a command prompt an type `ant -version`

Comment: Thank you.  Oddly enough, the result is 'ant' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.  Any further suggestions?

Comment: It may not be an Issue for running from eclipse but that suggests that `ANT_HOME` is not set. Check the [Ant Install Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html) on how to do this. Another thing to check would be to make sure you don't have multiple Java Paths in your Path

Comment: Thank you.  I checked, and there is only the one java path in my Path. ANT_HOME is not listed in the environmental variables, but the ant buildfile has run from within eclipse in the past.  I can try to set ANT_HOME when I have more time later.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Check out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288343/how-to-change-java-home-for-eclipse-ant) also to check your java home for eclipse, appears it is not the same as the windows java home.

Comment: Thank you.  Changing the Java Path within eclipse was what fixed the problem.  +1 for the silver bullet.

Answer (score 8):

The JDK is the whole installation bundle, not just the javac executable.

Your JAVA_HOME environment variable should point to the top of your JDK installation, in your case - this means:

C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\

Comment: I made an edit to my original posting above describing how the error is back again, even though windows tells me that the environmental variables are still set properly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\`  and  add `C:\mypath\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin` to `PATH`.

Comment: I made an edit to my original posting above describing how the error is back again, even though windows tells me that the environmental variables are still set properly.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on My computer/ThisPC and click on properties option.
2. Click on Advanced system settings.
3. Click on Environment Variables.
4. Add JAVA_HOME (to java home path) 
   Example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111
5. Add PATH(Path to Java bin directory) 
   Example: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin
6. Click on Apply and OK.

Visit this blog to see all steps with image: https://javatutorialdetails.blogspot.in/2017/10/how-java-program-work-step-by-step-in.html