# mvn install command working on mac terminal but not working from eclipse maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-plugin

I am trying to run 'mvn install' from maven eclipse plugin as follows

[image]

The build fails and throws MavenReportException:

Error while creating archive: Unable to find javadoc command: The environment variable JAVA_HOME is not correctly set.

However, I tried executing echo $JAVA_HOME and it displays /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home. Command java -version also displays the appropriate version.

Moreover, when I try running 'mvn install' from terminal the build succeeds. Why is build failing when running from eclipse maven plugin?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: who +1 my answer? :)

Comment: @user2938723 Please be gentle enough to accept an answer or update the thread.

Answer (score 4):

There is a difference between running from command line and from within eclipse. Each has its own variables. Your error states that you do not have set JAVA_HOME (in eclipse).

So, it seems like you have to set JAVA_HOME in eclipse.

[This SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288343/how-to-change-java-home-for-eclipse-ant) thread and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path) can help.

HTH

[How to change JAVA.HOME for Eclipse/ANT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288343/how-to-change-java-home-for-eclipse-ant)

[Setting up Eclipse with JRE Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394822/setting-up-eclipse-with-jre-path)

Comment: link only, please expand this.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to project->java build path->libraries->select "JRE System Library", click Edit and select "Workspace default JRE".

edit:
Also try Execution Environment -> Compatible JREs & set correct JRE.
(Or) Edit the eclipse.ini file to point to your jdk home, something as follows -
-vm /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home