# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit (rxtx)

Tags: java, dll, rxtx

I would like to use `rxtx` library  to connect to a serial port.
I've already tested a program that identifies available ports and communicate.However, when I export it as a runnable jar file.

I execute it with below command.

`java -jar prog.jar`

It shows this error and fails *`(Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit )`*

What can be wrong ?

Comment: can you specify more details on "i tested a program"? May be the way you tested it provided more jvm args.

Comment: i tested it in eclipse,i didn't do anything i just clicked on the run button in eclipse

Comment: You should check what jvm args eclipse adds when it is running it and use the same args for your `java -jar prog.jar`

Answer (score 0):

This provides some details on how to get jvm args used by eclipse...

[How can I specify the default JVM arguments for programs I run from eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10639322/how-can-i-specify-the-default-jvm-arguments-for-programs-i-run-from-eclipse)

In essence check Project Properties -> Run Configurations -> Arguments Tab ->JVM Args (second box below Program Arguments)
[image]
You should copy those arguments and use them in your `java <jvmArgs> -jar prog.jar`

Check JRE as per below you should use the java from this bin

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4440223/6935152
Project->Properties and choose Java Build Pathand choose the Libraries tab. Find the JRE System Library

Comment: the box is empty there are no vmArgument

Comment: Next you should check is Eclipse is using the same java as the one in your shell (where you are running from)

Comment: how i can  check it?

Comment: when i change the jre in eclipse the pogramme showed me the same probleme(can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform)

Comment: thank you sir ..i put the txrx dll file in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\jre\bin and the jar file worked

Comment: Ah, I expected you to do the other way round. As in use the original jre from Eclipse to run your program. That way we are not altering the way jre works. Putting this dll might effect another program that is using that console java adversely.

Comment: how i can use the jre that eclipse use in the console?

Comment: All you've to do is use the full path for java picked up from Eclipse where your test was running. Now there must be two choices of the jre in your Eclipse 1. Original 2. The version you copied the dll for. So you can choose 1 and see where the java bin path is.

Comment: The proper way to do it set the environment variable JAVA_HOME to bin path picked from original Eclipse and run java as you usually run it. But first test with full path to java then you can do this.

Comment: But I'll leave it to your choice. As the current setup is working for you, I would continue with the work.

Answer (score 0):

Right answer is %99.9 percent you have 64 bit JRE but running with 32bit rxtx. Just install  x86 runtime if possible. Problem will be solved.

Aslo consider putting **rxtxSerial.dll** into **syswow64** folder not system32.
Normally no need if they're in your classpath working directory.

> "The “WOW64” part of the name here refers to Microsoft’s “Windows
> 32-bit on Windows 64-bit” software, which is a part of the operating
> system. This allows Windows to run 32-bit programs on a 64-bit version
> of Windows. WoW64 redirects file access to ensure programs will work
> properly."

https://www.howtogeek.com/326509/whats-the-difference-between-the-system32-and-syswow64-folders-in-windows/

You can also consider following these steps.
http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Installation_for_Windows